# An inequality involving summation and products

Tags: inequality

I am trying to prove the following inequality (all the variables, ie, all $z_{i,j}$, are positive):

\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{1}{mk}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{k} z_{i, j}\right)^{k} \geq \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\prod_{j=1}^{k}z_{i,j}
\end{equation}

I checked that it holds for some trivial cases (taking, for example, $m=k=2$), but how do I generalize it?

For convenience (and if the inequality does not hold in general), you can take all the variables to be less than or equal to $1$).

Answer (score 2):

This is false. If $z_{i,j}=i$, $m=k=2$, LHS = $(\frac 64)^2 = 2.25$, RHS=$\frac 12 (1+4)=2.5 >$ LHS.

In fact, if you write $a_i, g_i$ as the arithmetic mean and geometric mean of $z_{i,j}$'s, respectively, your inequality becomes

$$\left( \frac{a_1+\cdots+a_m}{m} \right)^k \ge \frac 1m \sum_{i=1}^m g_i^k \tag 1$$

If $a_i=g_i$, but different across $i$'s then $(1)$ is reversed via the [power mean inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Power_Mean_Inequality).